# Can an annotation compiled with Java 6/7 be used on type parameters in Java 8?

Tags: java, annotations, java-8, type-annotation

The semantics of annotations that don't have `@Target` seems to have changed between [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html)

> If a Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type
>   declaration, the declared type may be used on **any** program element.

and [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html)

> If an @Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type T ,
>   then an annotation of type T may be written as a modifier for any
>   declaration **except a type parameter declaration**.

(emphasis mine).  This has the annoying consequence that any annotation compiled with Java 6/7 can't be used on a type parameter or type use.  Is there any way around this restriction?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the spec in the JavaDocs has changed is precisely to ensure that the semantics *didn't* change.  Annotations without a `@Target` can be used on packages, class/interface/enum/annotation type declarations, fields, constructors, methods, constructor and method parameters and local variable declarations, and this has *not* changed between Java 7 and 8.

Annotations couldn't be used on type parameter declarations or type uses *at all* before Java 8, so allowing un-`@Target`-ed annotations to be used in these situations would break the contract that existing annotation types that pre-date Java 8 agreed to.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense, but i interpreted the semantics of an absent `@Target` to mean "allowed anywhere, even in future language versions".  That's why the authors of JSR 330 didn't put `@Target` on `@Named`, for example, they wanted it to apply to type uses when they were added to the language.  Anyway, are you saying the answer to my question is "no"?